# Issue with proof of theorem $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I was understanding the proof until I got to the very end, and then this reference to the squeeze theorem threw me off.

Here is the section I  am struggling to understand:

$x<\sin x/\cos x$ therefore $ \cos x <(\sin x)/x<1$ (previously worked out)

Since the limit as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cos x =1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 1 =1$, then by the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

$\sin x$ is continuous so $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (\sin x)(x)=1$

What I don't understand is that the last statement seems to contradict the statement that $\cos x<(\sin x)/x<1$, if we take the limits of them and they're all equal, shouldn't the symbols be $\le$?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Also, why do we only take the lim x-> 0+ (sinx)/(x) first, instead of just taking lim x->0 ?

Comment: What does sine being continuous have to do with anything here?

Comment: If your problem is in the strict inequalities, note that $1<2\implies 1\leq 2$. In this case, $\cos x < \sin(x)/x < 1 \implies \cos x \leq \sin(x)/x \leq 1$

Comment: when taking the limit, we are never allowing $x$ to ever be equal to $0$; x approaches $0$, so there is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $x < { \sin x \over \cos x} <1$ holds for small $x>0$. This is why you are taking $\lim_{x \downarrow 0}$.

If $f(x) <g(x)$ for $x >0$ and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) $ and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} g(x) $ exist, then without any more conditions, the most you can say is
$\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) \le \lim_{x \downarrow 0} g(x) $. This does not contradict $f(x) <g(x)$ for $x >0$.

For example, take $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = x$. Then $0 <x$ for all $x >0$, but
$\lim_{x \downarrow 0} 0  = 0 = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} x $.

Continuity of $\sin$ is not relevant here, what is relevant is that $\sin$ is odd, so $x \mapsto { \sin x \over x}$ is even. This allows you to conclude
that $\lim_{x \to 0} { \sin x \over x} = 1$.

Note that when we write $\lim_{x \to 0} { \sin x \over x}$ we usually mean
$\lim_{x \to 0, x \neq 0} { \sin x \over x}$